# Create new table sans duplicate rows, preserve original order

Tags: php, mysql

A MySQL table has only 5 fields but hundreds of rows. With good advice (tks Lacoz) I have duplicated the table while ignoring the duplicate rows and now have a new table that does not contain the duplicated rows.

Problem: the new table was inputted in a scrambled order (i.e. when observing the first field, called `rel_id`). While this doesn't matter in the real world, at this point it would be helpful to have them in the same order (for referring to past notes, etc).

Example Row: (Note that `rel_id` is an auto-incrementing, primary key field)

```
'rel_id' => 1
'host' => 17
'host_type' => 'client'
'rep' => 7
'rep_type => 'cli_mgr'
```

Here is the method by which user Lacoz assisted me to create the new table, without duplicates:

```
mysql_query("create table rels2 like rels");
mysql_query("alter table rels2 add unique index(host,host_type,rep,rep_type)");
mysql_query("insert IGNORE into rels2 select * from rels");
```

I tried adding "ORDER BY" to the final query, like this:

```
mysql_query("insert IGNORE into rels2 select * from rels ORDER BY rel_id");
```

but it didn't solve the problem. Rows are still in scrambled order.

First Question: Why did this happen?

Second Question: How could I have ensured that the data was input in the correct order?

Necessary Outcome: For various reasons I really need the data returned to its former appearance (but sans the duplicates). Can someone suggest another approach, even a php script, to accomplish this?

PS: After several google searches I don't think it's possible to sort the table's raw data, only the output. Correct? (It is hard to be sure when a novice to both the concepts and the terminology - we all must start somewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, data in a relational database is not stored in any particular order. Mathematically, it's a set or relations, and sets have no ordering. That's why SQL doesn't provide any way to insert rows in a certain sequence (e.g. insert this row at the end, at the beginning, after some other row, etc...). It only provides a way to filter the output of a query given some specified ordering criteria.

Of course, a concrete implementation of SQL has to ultimately store things on disk in some kind of order, which is why you notice a repeatable ordering when you query a table without giving an `ORDER BY` clause, but you can't count on it. Your software should assume that rows will come out in arbitrary order.

If you need results to come out in a particular order, use `ORDER BY` on the query. Maybe build an appropriate index (if there isn't one already) to make sure the database can produce the ordering you request with good performance.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is precise and informative. However, I really need the data back in its original order. How could I accomplish the end result, even if a PHP script is required?

Comment: OK, but I attempted to explain that your code must not care about this. If it does, then it is fragile and liable to break unexpectedly do matter what you do (for example a MySQL upgrade or restore of a backup or something like that could break your application). So you're better off fixing the root problem than hacking around it. If you still want to hack around it then perhaps [user1718215's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277735/create-new-table-sans-duplicate-rows-preserve-original-order/13278205#13278205) will help.

Comment: There are moments when being an idiot comes round to bite one in the keister. Apparently, there's a dropdown I hadn't previously noticed in phpMyAdmin called "sort by key". Not an ideal solution, as it won't retain its setting, but nevertheless it's a solution. Thanks for restraining your laughter.

Answer (score 0):

AS YOU managed to solve the duplication by adding the unique index, you will have to load new primary key values if you want them to be auto_increment. So the proposed query is this

### `mysql_query("insert IGNORE into rels2(host,host_type,rep,rep_type)  select host,host_type,rep,rep_type from rels ORDER BY rel_id");`

Good luck!